# problem with MIT kinect demos

Tags: ros, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I have problem when trying to download the kinect demos.Actually when trying to download:

stacks/motion_planning_common/tags/unstable or /stacks/motion_planning_common/trunk/

the links that are used are unable. So i cannot rosmake or do anything else.

I want to use demos hand_interaction. Any ideas or any other similar demos???
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55295/problem--with-mit-kinect-demos/) by [ptsarouchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4212/ptsarouchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check this (https://)code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/stacks/motion_planning_common/trunk?rev=33669

ros.org use svn.

so use
svn checkout -r 33669 (https://)code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/

it will download many stacks including motion_planning_common

Please remove any brackets from the hyperlink

---

Originally posted by [promach](https://answers.ros.org/users/4286/promach/) with karma: 16 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0